# how to read from a remote git repository using python?

Tags: python, git

Is it possible to read directly from git repository using python? I tried using git-python but it reads from local git repository only.

Comment: why don't you clone the repo locally?

Comment: Actually I want to display the commit information in my application. This application is multi-tenant. So, I am thinking to access the repository via the git protocol : TCP or SSH

Answer (score 2):

The only git-python command which *may* let you query commits without cloning/fetching first would be `ls_remote`.

You can see an example in [`test/lib/helper.py#L168-179`](https://gitorious.org/git-python/mainline/source/e86eb305a542cee5b0ff6a0e0352cb458089bf62%3agit/test/lib/helper.py#L168-179):

```py
rw_repo.git.ls_remote(d_remote)
```

But that will return only the commits representing the branches/HEADS of a remote repo.

For any other history, you need to clone that remote repo first.

Answer (score 1):

See whether your Git Repo provides a REST API which enables access to the commit history.

For example, both [Github](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/commits/#get-a-commit) and [Gitlab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html#get-a-single-commit) provide such a feature.